# Javascript get data-validate value from input

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want to use a value from the data-validate in some javascript, how can i pick up the minAllowed

```
<input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="0.5" title="Aantal" class="input-text qty" data-validate="{&quot;required-number&quot;:true,&quot;validate-item-quantity&quot;:{&quot;minAllowed&quot;:0.5,&quot;maxAllowed&quot;:10000}}" />
```

I can get the value like this, is there some way to do the same with minAllowed?

```
var currentVal = parseInt($(this).parents('form').find('input[name="qty"]').val());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can take the value of that attribute by using the [data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method:

```js
const validate = $('input').data('validate');
const minAllowed = validate['validate-item-quantity'].minAllowed;

console.log(minAllowed);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" 
       name="qty" 
       id="qty" 
       maxlength="12" 
       value="0.5" 
       title="Aantal" 
       class="input-text qty" 
       data-validate="{&quot;required-number&quot;:true,&quot;validate-item-quantity&quot;:{&quot;minAllowed&quot;:0.5,&quot;maxAllowed&quot;:10000}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, can i use it like this    const validate = parseInt($(this).parents('form').find('input[name="qty"]').data('validate'));
            const minAllowed = validate['validate-item-quantity'].minAllowed;
            console.log(minAllowed);
            
            var amount = (minAllowed % 1 === 0) ? 1 : 0.1;

Comment: parseInt must be used on the minAllowed variable

Comment: const validate = $(this).parents('form').find('input[name="qty"]').data('validate');
            const minAllowed = parseInt(validate['validate-item-quantity'].minAllowed);
            console.log(minAllowed);
            
            var amount = (minAllowed % 1 === 0) ? 1 : 0.1;

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
let validate = $("#qty").data("validate"); // get the value "data-validate" 
let minAllowed = validate['validate-item-quantity'].minAllowed; // because the value is json, so you can just call it
console.log(minAllowed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var minValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("qty").min)
```